# Error to get values in array after push a new element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

anyone know how i solve it?
I added an element to my array with the push function and then tried to access the array at position 3 that was added to the element but not as defined

```
   readThis(inputValue: any): void {
    this.contImage = inputValue.files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.files.length; i++) {
        let file: File = inputValue.files[i];
        let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
            if(file.size <= 4000000){
                this.imageValues.push(myReader.result);
            }else{
                swal(
                    'Ops! Imagem muito grande',
                    'Algumas imagens não puderam ser enviados pois excede o tamanho maximo de 5 Megas :/',
                    'error'
                );
            }


        }
        myReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }

    this.editeImage();





}

editeImage(){

    console.log(this.imageValues[3]);



}
```

Comment: You need to call your `editeImage` function after the data is loaded, which means inside the `onloadend` function

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(this.imageValues)` and update your question with the output?

Comment: You are calling a position 3 in the array, but you can not guarantee that it is filled. Make an impression of the count of array elements. console.log(this.imageValues.length);

Answer (score 0):

You're getting tricked by asynchronicity.  Where you were previously calling the `editeImage` function, you had no guarantee that the necessary data was finished loaded.  You could call your `editeImage` function within the `onloadend` method to ensure you have data to work with.

```
readThis(inputValue: any): void {
  this.contImage = inputValue.files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.files.length; i++) {
    let file: File = inputValue.files[i];
    let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
      if(file.size <= 4000000){
        this.imageValues.push(myReader.result);
        if(this.imageValues.length === 4) this.editeImage();
      }else{
        swal(
          'Ops! Imagem muito grande',
          'Algumas imagens não puderam ser enviados pois excede o tamanho maximo de 5 Megas :/',
          'error'
        );
      }
    }
    myReader.readAsDataURL(file);

  }

}

editeImage(){ 
    console.log(this.imageValues[3]); 
}
```